# Cloud Firestore: Add collection and sub collection in one go

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Reading the documentation I can't see a way if this is possible in a sensible way.

I'm trying to create a document `team` with a sub document of `member`.

And what I'm really trying to achieve is an in-complex way of structuring read/writes/updates on collections and sub collections.

```
async createTeam(newTeam, foundingTeamMember) {
    const teams = db.collection('teams');
    const teamRef = await db.collection('teams').add(newTeam);
    const memberRef = await teams.doc(companyRef.id)
      .collection('members').add(foundingTeamMember);

    return({
       teamId: teamRef.id,
       memberId: memberRef.id,
    });
}
```

In particular is there a means of returning `teamId` and `memberId` without needing to use async / await?

Something like:

```
  db
    .collection('teams')

    .add(newTeam)
    .collection('members')
    .add(foundingTeamMember).then(/* return collection parent ID */)
```

Comment: what is your use case here? you are going to get invoiced for the 2 operations in both cases

Answer (score 0):

The random IDs for new documents are always generated on the client.  You can use the [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#doc) method on a CollectionReference with no parameters to generate a reference to a document that has a random ID without actually adding the document.  You can then work with that reference's [id property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#id) immeidately, and create the document later.

Comment: I didn’t know this, but it still creates the chicken and egg situation of one potentially finishing before the other.