# Reading firestore sub-collection data in react - how to set a parent id in the sub-collection where query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to read firestore sub collection data from react.

I have seen [this blog](https://dev.to/rossanodan/how-to-fetch-subcollections-from-cloud-firestore-with-react-3n93) that describes how to do it and am now trying to figure out how to implement the logic of it. I have also seen [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mo-sharif/bdd2cdfdb5b36d2501d2668227c840b8/raw/f2f4db3087381d2fe0b712ff74f5e5f5ad5be43f/s) which sets out a way to assign a parent id to a subcollection where query.

I have also been trying to understand this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hooks-with-firebase-firestore/), which I think is very close to what I am trying to do (it looks for the user collection id to populate the list of items subcollection data to render). I think the key to solving this problem is figuring out how to make a version of this function, but instead of monitoring a url parameter, I'm trying to use the particular glossaryTerm.id in the hook that looks for that glossary document's relatedTerms:
[image]

I have a parent collection called glossary and a sub collection within it called relatedTerms.

I have a form that works to correctly submit data to the glossary (parent) and relatedTerms (sub) collections.

I'm struggling to find a way to use react hooks to generate the list of glossary terms (this collection holds data) with associated related terms sub collection data).

My **current attempt** at doing that is:

```
function useGlossaryTerms() {
    const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    
    
   // First useEffect - to set the glossaryTerm (the parent document) 
    useEffect(() => {
    

async function fetchGlossaryData() {
          await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("glossary")
            .orderBy('term')
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
              const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
              }))
    

  

    setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
            });
fetchGlossaryData();
};
            // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        }, [])
        return glossaryTerms;
      };

    function useRelatedGlossaryTerms() {
    const [relatedGlossaryTerms, setRelatedGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()

    

     console.log("try logging from inside relatedTerms function", glossaryTerms)


    // Second useEffect - to set the relatedGlossaryTerm (the sub collection document)
      useEffect(() => {
  

    async function fetchRelatedGlossaryData() {
        await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("glossary")
          .doc([I'm trying to find a way to populate this field with the id of the glossary doc used in the map])
          //.doc("JsSQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2") works to render the placeholder text but without the subcollection document data.
          //.doc("glossary.id") gets ignored

          // {console.log("testing:", glossaryTerms)}
          .collection('relatedTerms')
          
          //.where("glossaryId", "==", "glossaryTerms.id")
```

> **** This is wrong, but I can't find a way that works. I think I'm trying to ask for the state of glossaryTerms and then the id on the
> relevant object" ****

```
//              .where("glossaryId", "==", "JsSQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2"
```

> **** This is also wrong, but I can't understand why. If the above attempt is not possible because glossaryTerms is an object, then that
> element of this problem should be solved by using the string stored on
> the subcollection document. It doesn't work. It doesn't generate any
> console errors and I still can't find a way to log the value of the
> subcollection." ****

```
          .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            }))
            setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
          });
fetchRelatedGlossaryData();
}
         
          // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
      }, [glossaryTerms])
      return relatedGlossaryTerms;
    };
    
    
      
    
    const GlossaryTerms = () => {
    
        const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = useRelatedGlossaryTerms()
          


    const classes = useStyles();

    return ( 
        
            <div className={classes.root}>
            
            {glossaryTerms.map(glossaryTerm => {
{console.log('testing log of glossaryTerms', glossaryTerms)}
                return (
                    <div key={glossaryTerm.id}>
                
                    
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>{glossaryTerm.term}</Typography>
                    
                    <div>
                    
                    {glossaryTerm.category.map(category => (
                        <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
                        {category.label}
                        </Typography>
                    )

                    )}
                    
                   
                    <div>    
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.heading2}>Meaning</Typography>
                        <Typography>{glossaryTerm.definition}</Typography>
                    </div>
                       
{console.log("testing log of  glossaryTerm", glossaryTerm)}
```

> - this works to log the single glossaryTerm in the map.

```
                {console.log("testing log of  relatedGlossaryTerm", relatedGlossaryTerms)}
```

> - this returns an empty array. This doesn't make any sense to me. The glossaryTerm with the id returned in the log above has a subcollection
>   (called relatedTerms) with data that should be used to populate the
>   relatedGlossaryTerms state.

```
                    <div>
                    {relatedGlossaryTerms ? (
                      <ul>
                        {relatedGlossaryTerms.map(relatedGlossaryTerm => (
                          <div key={relatedGlossaryTerm.id}>
                            <Typography variant="caption">
                            Placeholder title {relatedGlossaryTerm.title} | 
                            Placeholder description {relatedGlossaryTerm.description} 
                            </Typography>
                          </div>  
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    ) : null}


                                                {
                            glossaryTerm.templates ? (
                              <div>    
                                <p><Typography variant="caption" >Related Templates</Typography></p>
                                {glossaryTerm.templates.map(template => (
                                    
                                    <Link to="" className="bodylinks"  key={template.id}>
                                      <p><Typography variant="caption" >{template.title}
                                      </Typography></p>
                                    </Link>
                                ))}
                              </div>
                            ) : null
                          }
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        
                 

            )
        })}
            </div>
            
        </div>   
</div>
     );
}
 
export default GlossaryTerms;
```

When I try this, I don't get any errors in the console, but, the rendered output is incorrect and confusing.

The glossary currently has 2 documents in that collection. One of the documents has a relatedTerms subcollection which also has 2 documents. The other has no sub collection entries (other than a glossaryId field which I add to the setSubmitting form add so that I could try matching the string ids to filter sub collection documents - this attempt is outlined in the history of this post and does not work. I think it may need group collection queries - but I don't think this approach should be necessary to access a single subcollection from a parent id).

Whilst the glossary data is correctly rendered, the sub collection data for relatedTerms is not rendered at all - BUT the placeholder text is repeated for each instance of the parent collection (2 documents). I currently have 2. If I add another entry to the sub collection to test this, the 2 placeholder sets of text are repeated in each glossary document rendered.

The image below shows the rendered output.
[image]

The image below shows the content of the glossary collection.

[image]

The image below shows the content of the relatedTerms sub collection.

[image]

This is confusing, because the placeholder text is repeated the same number of times as is equal to the number of parent collection document entries. It's not testing for sub collection values.

It's also incorrect because I can't find a way to join the relatedTerm to its relevant glossaryTerm collection entry. Each item in the list should render its sub collection content only.

When I try logging the relatedGlossaryTerms, as follows:

```
 {console.log("testing log of relatedGlossaryTerms", relatedGlossaryTerms)}
                    {relatedGlossaryTerms ? (
                      
                      <ul>
                        {relatedGlossaryTerms.map(relatedGlossaryTerm => (
```

I get:

[image]

This log is confusing to me because it's supposed to be the content of the sub collection. Instead it logs the parent collection.

I can't find a way to log the value of the relatedGlossaryTerms.

When I try adding console log statements to the snapshot, I get errors that I can't understand. Plenty of other posts show this as a correct method to use to log the values. I tried adding curly braces, but get the same issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc()
      // {console.log("testing:", glossaryTerms)}
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      // .where("glossaryId" === "SQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          
      
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
          // console.log('test useEffect setting for relatedGlossaryTerms', doc),
          // console.log(relatedGlossaryTerms)
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
        
      });
```

When I try logging the values of glossaryTerms and relatedGlossaryTerms in the return statement, I get:

[image]
[image]
**Trying Yoruba's (now deleted) suggestion**

I tried Yoruba's suggestion to use get instead of snapshot. Although it does not make sense to me as to why I can't use snapshot without mobx, I tried it.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("glossary")
        .orderBy('term')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))

          setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        });
        // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
    }, [])
    return glossaryTerms;
  

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc()
      // {console.log("testing:", glossaryTerms)}
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      // .where("glossaryId" === "SQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          
      
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
          
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
        
      });
     
      // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
  }, [glossaryTerms])
  return relatedGlossaryTerms;
};
```

It doesn't make any difference. No new console errors. No difference to the rendering problems outlined above.

**ALL PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS**

```
 onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                     setSubmitting(true);
                     
                    //  firestore.collection("glossary").doc().set({
                    //   ...values,
                    //   createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                    //   })
                    // .then(() => {
                    //   setSubmitionCompleted(true);
                    // });
                  // }}
                  const newDocRef = firestore.collection("glossary").doc() // auto generated doc id saved here
  let writeBatch = firestore.batch();
  {console.log("logging values:", values)};
  writeBatch.set(newDocRef,{
    term: values.term,
    definition: values.definition,
    category: values.category,
    context: values.context,
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  });
  writeBatch.set(newDocRef.collection('relatedTerms').doc(),{
    // dataType: values.dataType,
    // title: values.title,
    glossaryId: newDocRef.id,
    ...values.relatedTerms
    // description: values.description,
  })
  writeBatch.commit()
    .then(() => {
      setSubmitionCompleted(true);
    });
}}
```

No error message is shared when I try this, the glossaryId just gets ignored. It remains a mystery to me what the batch concept is- I thought it only ran if all the instructions could be performed.

I'm trying to figure out how to access the data stored in the sub collection. My current attempt at doing that is based on the example in the post linked above.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import firebase, { firestore } from "../../../../firebase.js";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: '8vh',
    marginBottom: '5vh'
  },
 
}));


function useGlossaryTerms() {
    const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    const [relatedGlossaryTerms, setRelatedGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("glossary")
        .orderBy('term')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))
          setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        });
        // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
    }, [])
    return glossaryTerms;
  }

  const relatedTermsList = (glossaryTerm) => {
    setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerm);
    firebase.firestore().collection('glossary').doc(glossaryTerm.id).collection('relatedTerms').get()
      .then(response => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = [];
        response.forEach(document => {
          const relatedGlossaryTerm = {
            id: document.id,
            ...document.data()
          };
          relatedGlossaryTerms.push(relatedGlossaryTerm);
        });
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // setError(error);
      });
  }
  

const GlossaryTerms = () => {

    const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
    const relatedGlossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
        
    const classes = useStyles();

    return ( 
        <div>
            {glossaryTerms.map(glossaryTerm => {
                return (
                    
               {glossaryTerm.term}
                    {glossaryTerm.category.map(category => (
                        
                        {category.label}
                        
                    )

                    )}
                    
                    </div>
               {glossaryTerm.definition}

                    {glossaryTerm ? (
                      <ul>
                        {relatedGlossaryTerms.map(relatedGlossaryTerm => (
                          <li key={relatedGlossaryTerm.id}>
                            {relatedGlossaryTerm.title} | {relatedGlossaryTerm.description} 
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    ) : null}

                    
            )
        })}
            </div>
            
         

     );
}
 
export default GlossaryTerms;
```

When I try this, I get error messages saying that in my relatedTermsList const, the definitions of setGlossaryTerms and setRelatedGlossaryTerms are undefined.

Each of these errors are odd to me because setRelatedGlossaryTerms is defined in the same way as setGlossaryTerms. I don't understand why it is unrecognisable and setGlossaryTerms is used in the useEffect without any issue.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I tried using a second useEffect function that takes a glossaryTerm.

```
function useGlossaryTerms() {
    const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    const [relatedGlossaryTerms, setRelatedGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("glossary")
        .orderBy('term')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))
          setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        });
        // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
    }, [])
    return glossaryTerms;
  }

  useEffect((glossaryTerm) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc(glossaryTerm.id)
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // setError(error);
      });
  });
  

const GlossaryTerms = () => {

    const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
    const relatedGlossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
        
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
```

I don't understand why, but the error is that setRelatedGlossaryTerms is not defined - where it's used in the second useEffect.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

This attempt does not produce any errors in the console but the result is incorrect.

I have two useEffect functions as follows:

```
function useGlossaryTerms() {
    const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    const [relatedGlossaryTerms, setRelatedGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("glossary")
        .orderBy('term')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))
          setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        });
        // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
    }, [])
    return glossaryTerms;
  

  useEffect((glossaryTerms) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc("glossaryTerms.id") //I also tried .doc(glossaryTerms.id)
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
      });
      // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
  }, [])
  return relatedGlossaryTerms;
};


  

const GlossaryTerms = () => {

    const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
    const relatedGlossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
        
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
```

The intention behind these two useEffects is that the first one finds the glossaryTerm and then the second one uses the glossaryTerm.id to find if there are any related terms and then sets the state of the relatedGlossaryTerms array with any related terms.

Then in the render, I have:

```
 {glossaryTerm.category.map(category => (
                        <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
                        {category.label}
                        </Typography>
                    )
```

The above works to correctly find the glossaryTerm.

```
{relatedGlossaryTerms ? (
                      <ul>
                        {relatedGlossaryTerms.map(relatedGlossaryTerm => (
                          <div>
                            <Typography variant="caption">
                            Placeholder title {relatedGlossaryTerm.title} | 
                            Placeholder description {relatedGlossaryTerm.description} 
                            </Typography>
                          </div>  
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    ) : null}
```

The intention is for the above to look to see if there are any relatedGlossaryTerms (which should be the result of finding the sub collection inside the glossaryTerm.

This doesn't produce any console errors, but it does 2 things that need to be corrected.

1. it renders the same result for each glossaryTerm (regardless of whether it actually has any relatedGlossaryTerms.
2. It does not render the relatedGlossaryTerm data. The picture below shows the placeholder text printed, repeatedly (as many times as is equal to the total number of related terms in all glossaryTerms documents combined).

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to use the glossaryTerm document id to find the sub collection data and render it only inside the relevant glossaryTerm item.

**Next Attempt**

I also tried:

```
useEffect((glossaryTermsId) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc(glossaryTermsId)
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      .where(glossaryTermsId === "glossaryId") // I also tried .where(glossaryTerms.id === "glossaryId)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))

    setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
  });
```

I have added a field to the sub collection called glossaryId to try to use the where query to filter the sub collection (although even if this worked, which it doesn't) - I don't want to search every glossaryTerm document to get the right relatedTerms.

[image]
When I try

```
useEffect((glossaryTerms) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc(glossaryTerms)
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      .where("glossaryId" === "JsSQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
      });
```

I still get the same result as shown in the picture above (just the placeholder text prints - the same way in all of the glossaryTerms - it just ignores the query parameter of the glossaryId attribute in the sub collection document.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I'm scratching for ideas for things to try now. I've tried adding glossaryTerms as a dependency to the second useEffect and I tried giving the glossaryTermsId as a prop (instead of the glossaryTerms object), as follows:

```
useEffect((glossaryTermsId) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc(glossaryTermsId)
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      // .where("glossaryId" === "JsSQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
      });
      // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
  }, [glossaryTerms])
  return relatedGlossaryTerms;
};
```

Neither of these things make any difference to the outcomes shown above.

When I try to log the content of glossaryTerm in the render - one strange thing is that the sub collection data is not displayed. I only have 2 test entries in the glossary collection. 1 has a related term and the other doesn't. Neither is visible in the console log. I think this is because of shallow queries. But, I can't then find a way to link the collection query to the sub collection data.

[image]

**Next attempt**

Taking Bennett's advice, I removed the parameters from the useEffect as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("glossary")
      .doc()
      // {console.log("testing:", glossaryTerms)}
      .collection('relatedTerms')
      
      // .where("glossaryId" === "JSQ3Qf0A65ixNbF07G2")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const relatedGlossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        setRelatedGlossaryTerms(relatedGlossaryTerms)
      });
     
      // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
  }, [glossaryTerms])
  return relatedGlossaryTerms;
};
```

When I try this, it still renders the same output as shown in the image above.

When I uncomment the where query (which is the doc id of a document which has a sub collection for relatedTerms, I'm expecting to be able to get to the subcolleciton data (even if its in all the glossaryTerms, instead of just the one to which the sub collection belongs).

Instead, I get the placeholder text, rendered the number of times as is equal to the total number of related terms recorded in all sub collections in all the glossaryTerms documents (but no data).

Then when I change the string, so it should evaluate to null, I get the same rendered output (still prints the placeholders).

Comment: There's one big problem with your basic setup: `useEffect` will & can never have a parameter for its callback, e. g. `useEffect((glossaryTermsId) => {` the `glossaryTermsId` will always be `undefined` & ignored in that `useEffect`'s code, which will lead to many other problems. Even if you defined a variable outside of the `useEffect` with the same name, it will be overwritten by the `useEffect`'s callback, so it's undefined in the `useEffect` itself. Remove the callback parameters (like `glossaryTermsId`) on every `useEffect` you're using. https://codesandbox.io/s/little-hill-bikps

Comment: Thanks @BennettDams. That's helpful. I removed the parameter from the 2nd use effect. I am lost for how I can get to the sub collection data. Do you know where I can find an example of how to do it in react hooks? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure which "2nd use effect" you mean, but if it is the one from your first example (and you removed the parameter), the following will not work: `.doc("glossaryTerms.id")`, because `glossaryTerms` is an array and not an object. I think it would be helpful if you would update your question with one specific setup to discuss, it is hard to follow with all your attempts. It would also make sense for you to go through each line and `console.log` each variable you're using, so it's clear WHERE exactly the issue occurs.

Comment: I think you have to get the data from firestore without the listener onSnapshot. Instead use Get data once https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data. If you want to use a listener it is better you use a store like https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/

Comment: thanks @BennettDams - I added a new opener to this post which just uses the current attempt. I've tried logging the value of relatedGlossaryTerms, but it returns the value of glossaryTerms - which is strange. Any ideas on where I can look for things to try? Thank you again.

Comment: thanks @Yoruba - I tried your suggestion just in case it worked. I've added a section to this post beneath the current attempt which shows that attempt. It didn't change anything. Is there a reason that you think that snapshot does not work without a state handler? It seems to be working fine to get parent collection data. Thank you

Comment: It seems that it may not be possible to get to a subcollection from a primary document. I just found this blog post https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166 and am exploring it now.

Comment: Next: I just found this blog. It's complicated in that it uses a URL param query to populate a string in the firestore query - but I think it is a clue to solving this problem. https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hooks-with-firebase-firestore/

Comment: I have to wait a day before I can make a new bounty to seek help for this problem - I'll do it again tomorrow to try and find help.

Answer (score 2):

I did try with real data like you db but you can't list subcollections of a document.
I think the best way is the create a separate collection for relatedTerms and during save to database you have the save the form data into 2 separate collections.
Or build you viewmodel at the backend with firebase functions and send this to the view.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web_6

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Yoruba - that feature is to list all the sub collections. I'm trying to get a specific subcollection - which I think should be possible. I just don't know how to do it. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Mel it is not gona work the way you want. What works is first get the glossary collection and then get every relatedTerms one by one or get one by parentId. And don't use useEffect for getting the child use a async function for that. Just do it old fashion with a react component which is getting the parent and a child view which is get the selected parent.

Comment: @Mel just do it like the blog. With useEffect get the glossary collection and then get the child collection when someone clicks on a button. And relatedGlossary is an object with an array and not an array. So const [relatedGlossaryTerms, setRelatedGlossaryTerms] = useState()

Comment: In any event, the data is setup in two separate collections. I have one collection (glossary) and another (relatedTerms). I'll share an answer if I find one. Thanks again for your effort to try to help.

Comment: For others trying to solve a similar problem, this answer is irrelevant. There are not multiple sub collections. There is a single sub collection.

Comment: i gave you points to acknowledge the time you put into this - although for others reading this, these responses are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
const collectionref = collection(fire, 'FirstLevel/' + doc + '/LastLevel');
    onSnapshot(collectionref, (querysnapshot) => { console.log("Read Msg");
 const msgstream = querysnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ data: doc.data(), id: doc.id }));  
console.log(msgstream) }, (error) => { console.log(error.message) });
```

replace FirstLevel with your main collection and concat with doc then add nested collection in LastLevel make sure to catch error is the event the nested collection doesnt exist.

check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score -1):

This works but the view gets loaded for every glossary child.
Also the database is hit for every glossary child.
That's why it is better to put relatedTerms into a separate collection.
Then you can get the glossary collection with 1 db call and the relatedTerms with 1 db call.

```
  const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
  const [relatedGlossaryTerms, setRelatedGlossaryTerms] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // get the glossary collection
   firebase.firestore()
   .collection("glossary").orderBy('term').get().then(glossaries => {
      let tempGlossaryTerms = []
      let tempRelatedGlossaryTerms = []

      glossaries.forEach(doc => {
        const glossary = {id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
        tempGlossaryTerms.push(glossary)

        // for each glossary get the related term
        firebase.firestore()
          .collection("glossary")
          .doc(glossary.id)
          .collection('relatedTerms')
          .get().then(relatedTerms => {
            relatedTerms.docs.forEach(doc => {
              const relatedTerm = {id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
              tempRelatedGlossaryTerms.push(relatedTerm)
            })
            setRelatedGlossaryTerms(tempRelatedGlossaryTerms)
          })

      })
      setGlossaryTerms(tempGlossaryTerms)
    })
  }, [])
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood the set up that I have. relatedTerms is a subcollection of glossary (as shown in the snapshots). I appreciate your efforts to help. I'm looking for a solution that fetches the documents in related terms for a glossary document. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Mel there is a collection with glossary and every glossary has a collection of terms. Do you want to show all glossaries with the terms what this code do. Or do you want to show all glossaries and show the terms of the selected glossary like what is described in the post?

Comment: It's a list mapping over each glossary term, displaying attributes on that glossary document, along with relatedTerms subcollection document attributes. The code shared is of the list index, which maps over each item in the glossary collection. The hooks get the glossary data successfully. The step that I'm struggling with is how to populate the hook that gets the subcollection data, with the parent glossary document id.

Comment: @Mel there is no big collection of terms. Every glossary has his own collection of terms.

Comment: That's correct. Each subcollection is a subset of glossary.

Comment: I don't think we have understood each other well. I appreciate all your effort to help. I'll post a solution if I find one. The article I linked in the comments above is the closest thing I've found to guidance at this point. If I can find a way of implementing it, I'll share it here.

Comment: For completeness, I tried your suggestion. It fails, because it cannot map over glossaryTerms. Thank you again for giving this problem your consideration. I'll share a solution if I find one.